# Looking to change numpy array of size (m,2) to timestamps in form hh:mm AM/PM

Tags: python, numpy, timestamp

I am having a tough time making a function that takes a numpy array of size = (m,2) and results a 12 hour format timestamp of hours and minutes. I would like to use `time()` from the `from datetime import time` library.

Knowing that

```
from datetime import time

timestamp = time(13,15)
print(timestamp.strftime('%I:%M %p'))
```

has the output of `01:15 PM`.

I'd like to take a numpy array such as (where it accounts for numbers larger than 24 as the number `m` as `m//24`

```
a = np.array([[0,40],[13,20],[42,20]])
```

and have the result of the function `function(array)` be

```
function(a)
```

with the output being a list of timestamps

```
[12:40 AM, 1:20 PM, 6:20 PM]
```

While I'd like to use the `time` library from `datetime`, I'd be open to learning how to do this by printing strings as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you meant `hrs > 24 -> hrs % 24` (to get the remaining hours, not the number of full days).

This can be achieved with [`np.apply_along_axis`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html) to apply your time conversion function to each row:

```py
import numpy as np
from datetime import time

def row_to_time(row):
    return time(row[0] % 24, row[1]).strftime('%I:%M %p')

def array_to_times(arr):
    return np.apply_along_axis(row_to_time, 1, arr)

a = np.array([[0,40],[13,20],[42,20]])
print(array_to_times(a)) # -> ['12:40 AM' '01:20 PM' '06:20 PM']
```

As far as I'm aware, the requirement to create a string for each row means you can't vectorise this meaningfully, so that might be as good as you can get.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about `numpy.apply_along_axis()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
def convert_time(arr):
    ret = []
    am = 'A.M'
    pm = 'P.M'
    for i, j in enumerate(arr):
        if arr[i][0] < 12:
            if arr[i][0] == 0:
                arr[i][0] += 12
            ret.append(f"{arr[i][0]}:{arr[i][1]} {am}")
        elif arr[i][0] > 24:
            arr[i][0] = arr[i][0] % 24 - 12
            ret.append(f"{arr[i][0]}:{arr[i][1]} {pm}")
        elif arr[i][0] >= 12:
            if arr[i][0] != 12:
                arr[i][0] -= 12
            ret.append(f"{arr[i][0]}:{arr[i][1]} {pm}")
    return ret
```

INPUT:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0,40],[13,20],[42,20]])

convert_time(a)
```

OUTPUT:

```
['12:40 A.M', '1:20 P.M', '6:20 P.M']
```